# A chapter's homepage style

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I would like to customize the chapter numbering background, but so that it only appears with the `\chapter` command and so it does not appear when using `\chapter*`.

Also I would like the word chapter to appear only when using the `\chapter` command.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{,positioning,matrix,calc, shapes.arrows, shadows.blur,shadows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       CHAPTER     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}


\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
    \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
        (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[xshift=.5\paperwidth,rectangle,
        rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
        fill=MidnightBlue]
        {\color{white}#1};%anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth
        \node[yshift=1.5cm, anchor=west,rectangle,inner sep=11pt, fill=MidnightBlue]
        {\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont{\chapterlabel}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{title}
\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want no background for unnumbered chapter, only the default formatting?

Comment: yes, and I would like to display the word chapter only in the chapters that are numbered

Comment: One solution would be to use the `inner sep = 0pt` option. But I would like to know a way to separately format what happens when using `\chapter` or `\chapter*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've well understood what you want, you can have an easy solution  with the `numberless` key for `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing*`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{,positioning,matrix,calc, shapes.arrows, shadows.blur,shadows}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}


\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
    \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
        (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[xshift=.5\paperwidth,rectangle,
        rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
        fill=MidnightBlue]
        {\color{white}#1};%anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth
        \node[yshift=1.5cm, anchor=west,rectangle,inner sep=11pt, fill=MidnightBlue]
        {\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont{\chapterlabel}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]
{ \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape\filcenter}
{}{0pt}
{#1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]
{ \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape\filcenter}
{}{0pt}
{#1}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{-70pt}{60pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{title}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{title}
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It was only the background color of the chapter number defined by the node `\node[yshift=1.5cm, anchor=west,rectangle,inner sep=11pt, fill=MidnightBlue]{\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont{\chapterlabel}};`

Comment: The `numberless` option that you presented allows me to define separately how the numbered and unnumbered chapters will be. This was enough to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: It tripped me up for a long time, but for other LaTeX noobs, the optional [explicit] is important here for being able to reference 'title':  `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`.